# Getting 404 using JQL to query Jira issue via Java

Tags: java, url, jira-rest-api, jql, jira-rest-java-api

I am consistently getting 404 response code when trying to query for an issue in Jira via Java/JQL/Jira API.  The Urls below - when plugged in directly into the browser, i get correct results for both.  Only via Java API do I get 404.  I suspect something is wrong with the URI encoding but cannot figure it out.

Side note - the httpGet() works fine for every other Jira request I put together (Zapi, REST call, etcl), just not this particular one for whatever reason.

```
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.net.Proxy;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URL;

...

String urlStr = "https://jira.xxxx.com//jira/rest/api/2/issue/search?jql=project=XXXXX and summary ~ \"Testing Jira Integration Pass\"&fields=id,key,summary";

logger.debug("Url: " + urlStr.toString());

URL url = new URL(urlStr);
URI uri = new URI(url.getProtocol(), url.getUserInfo(), url.getHost(), url.getPort(), url.getPath(), url.getQuery(), url.getRef());
url = uri.toURL();

logger.debug("Url Encoded: " + url.toString());

HttpURLConnection conn = httpGet(url.toString(), null, null);
logger.debug("Http Response Code: " + conn.getResponseCode());
```

Results:

```
2016-05-26 06:27:55 DEBUG - Url: https://jira.xxxx.com//jira/rest/api/2/issue/search?jql=project=XXXXX and summary ~ "Testing Jira Integration Pass"&fields=id,key,summary
2016-05-26 06:27:55 DEBUG - Url Encoded: https://jira.xxxx.com//jira/rest/api/2/issue/search?jql=project=XXXXX%20and%20summary%20~%20%22Testing%20Jira%20Integration%20Pass%22&fields=id,key,summary
2016-05-26 06:27:55 DEBUG - Http Response Code: 404
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had it all wrong.  I had to build the request into a JSON string, once i did that, and used the correct URL, and did POST, it worked.

```
String url = buildUrl("jira/rest/api/2/search");
    String query = "project = XXXX AND issuetype = Test AND text ~ \"" + testId + "\"";

JSONArray fields = new JSONArray();
fields.put("id");
fields.put("key");
fields.put("summary");

JSONObject reqObj = new JSONObject();
reqObj.put("jql", query);
reqObj.put("startAt", 0);
reqObj.put("maxResults", 15);
reqObj.put("fields", fields);

String requestBody = reqObj.toString();
logger.debug("Request body: " + requestBody);

HttpURLConnection conn = httpPost(url, null, null, requestBody);
logger.debug("HTTP response code: " + conn.getResponseCode());
String response = IOUtils.toString(conn.getInputStream());
logger.debug("HTTP res content: " + response);
```